# IA-32e 64-bit IDT Gate Descriptor

Tags: assembly, operating-system, intel, x86-64

There is a Segment Selector in Intel's 64-bit IDT Gate Descriptor. However, from my understanding across the 5 part Intel manuals, the Linear Address of the Interrupt Handler is loaded into RIP from the 64-bit offset specified in the IDT Gate Descriptor.

The only use of the segment selector is to check:

1. if there is a change in privilege levels
2. the Interrupt Handler is truly pointing to a code segment

My questions then is:

1. Is RIP taken from the 64-bit offset only? Or is RIP = offset(sign extended to 64-bits) + segment selector base?
2. Is the base address pointed to by the segment selector in the IDT Gate Descriptor ignored? Or does it have a use?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I'm interpreting this correctly, according to the intel manuals, x64 does not use segmentation. I read [AMD's System programming for AMD64](http://support.amd.com/us/Processor_TechDocs/APM_V2_24593.pdf) to make sense of this as I found their explanations much easier to follow as they explicitly deal with x86_64 (they did invent it, I suppose); they state:

> In long mode, the effects of segmentation depend on whether the processor is running in compatibility
>   mode or 64-bit mode:
>
> - In compatibility mode, segmentation functions just as it does in legacy mode, using legacy 16-bit or 32-bit protected mode semantics.
> - 64-bit mode, segmentation is disabled, creating a flat 64-bit virtual-address space. As will be seen, certain functions of some
>     segment registers, particularly the system-segment registers, continue
>     to be used in 64-bit mode.

Specifically, look for section 4.8 Long-Mode Segment Descriptors. To answer your second question:

> Fields Ignored in 64-Bit Mode. Segmentation is disabled in 64-bit
>   mode, and code segments span all of virtual memory. In this mode, code-segment base addresses are ignored. For the purpose of virtual-address calculations, the base address is treated as if it has a value of zero.

To interpret: because a "segment" in x86_64 is the whole address space, a base address does not make sense except for 0, since offsets are all absolute (relative to 0).

This would therefore answer the first question I believe - RIP is taken as the 64-bit offset value. From the gate descriptor page of the same chapter:

> In long mode, gate descriptors are expanded by 64 bits, allowing them to hold 64-bit offsets.

It gets more complicated when dealing with data segments though:

> Data segments referenced by the FS and GS segment registers receive special treatment in 64-bit
>   mode. For these segments, the base address field is not ignored, and a non-zero value can be used
>   in virtual-address calculations. A 64-bit segment-base address can be specified using model-
>   specific registers. See “FS and GS Registers in 64-Bit Mode” on page 70 for more information.

That section states:

> FS and GS Registers in 64-Bit Mode. Unlike the CS, DS, ES, and SS segments, the FS and GS
>   segment overrides can be used in 64-bit mode. When FS and GS segment overrides are used in 64-bit
>   mode, their respective base addresses are used in the effective-address (EA) calculation. The complete
>   EA calculation then becomes (FS or GS).base + base + (scale ∗ index) + displacement. The FS.base
>   and GS.base values are also expanded to the full 64-bit virtual-address size, as shown in Figure 4-5.
>   The resulting EA calculation is allowed to wrap across positive and negative addresses.
>
> In 64-bit mode, FS-segment and GS-segment overrides are not checked for limit or attributes. Instead,
>   the processor checks that all virtual-address references are in canonical form.

In other words, data segments can act like segmentation is used, although only the form of segmentation is checked, rather than checking whether the form of access lies within the bounds of the segment.

I think that is the right interpretation; however, corrections/pointers very much appreciated.

Comment: Modern Intel processors do not use segmentation. I think the last Intel processor that supported segmentation was the Pentium II.

Comment: @this.josh: I beg to differ: all Intel and AMD processors from the 80386, including the most recent ones, _do_ support segmentation as specified in 32-bit mode. _Operating Systems_ choose not to use segments, at least most of the time (on 32-bit x86, with Linux, the `gs` segment register is used to implement thread-local storage). Consequently, the support for segment registers with a non-zero base address is not thoroughly optimized in recent processors -- but it still works.

Comment: @ThomasPornin Oops, my mistake.

Comment: Thanks for the awesome answer and the link to the AMD Hardware Manual. I should have thought of that :) After comparing the relevant sections in the Intel and AMD manuals, I believe we are on the right track. Thanks loads once again! Cheers!